# FireDAC Query connect to DBGrid

Tags: c++builder, dbgrid

I have FDQuery and DataSource and DBGrid. Now I write this code in Button

```
  FDQuery2->Active = false;
  FDQuery2->SQL->Clear();
  FDQuery2->SQL->Add(" SELECT C.patient_id, P.patient_name, C.check_id "
                  " FROM Checkup C "
                  " INNER JOIN Patient P ON (C.patient_id=P.patient_id) "
                  " WHERE C.today = " + MaskEdit1->Text +
                  " ORDER BY C.check_id ");
  FDQuery2->Active = true;
```

and i connect FDQuery to DataSource and tDataSource to DBGrid, but when I click the Button it doesn't show rows. and i am sure that SQL code is work, because when i write inside the SQL String the rows have been shown.
any ideas.

Comment: What datatype is the column `C.today`? Also, please be more careful with your tag selections - `builder` does not refer to C++ Builder (the `c++builder` tag does). Tags here have specific meanings; please read the description before using it. Using the proper tags gets your question in front of the people who can answer it, as well as classifying them properly for future users searching for an answer. Thanks.

Comment: the data type is text

Comment: You're welcome. :-) It helps if you provide that sort of information in your question; we don't have any information about what you're doing except what you tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `'` around your value when concatenating the text. Change your `WHERE` clause:

```
FDQuery2->SQL->Clear();
FDQuery2->SQL->Add(" SELECT C.patient_id, P.patient_name, C.check_id "
                " FROM Checkup C "
                " INNER JOIN Patient P ON (C.patient_id=P.patient_id) "
                " WHERE C.today = '" + MaskEdit1->Text + "'" +
                " ORDER BY C.check_id ");
```

You really should learn to use parameterized queries instead, though. It allows the database driver to handle things like properly quoting text or formatting dates for you, and it also (importantly) prevents SQL injection.

```
FDQuery2->SQL->Clear();
FDQuery2->SQL->Add(" SELECT C.patient_id, P.patient_name, C.check_id "
                " FROM Checkup C "
                " INNER JOIN Patient P ON (C.patient_id=P.patient_id) "
                " WHERE C.today = :today" + 
                " ORDER BY C.check_id ");
FDQuery2->ParamByName("today")->AsString = MaskEdit1.Text;
FDQuery2->Active = true;
```

Comment: and it works .. but there is another Problem.
i have a datasource as i said and each time i change the value of "today" i should refresh it


   DataSource1->DataSet->Refresh();


it's OK .. but when i delete a record from the table and ApplyUpdate(-1) and then refresh() the datasource that is connected to just the query it said "you should apply update before refresh" !

Comment: That "other problem" is a new problem that is not related to this one, and you should create a new question to ask about it. You can link back to this one for reference. The problem in this question has been answered. :-) You can post your code that's attempting to do the delete/applyupdates/refresh in that new question where we can see it.